# Android music player app update player screen in background

Tags: android, user-interface, background

I have a music player app, in the player screen there is a progress bar, a volume control, an imageview that shows the song's album cover, etc.

When I leave the player screen the sound keeps playing but I want to be able to go back to the player screen and see the UI updated (song progress updated, etc.). What is the best way to save this? Should I use something like SharedPreferences and when the player activity starts get all the data and update the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is listen events from service when UI is showing, you can subscribe to player in onStart and unsubscribe in onStop methods.